# Posting JSON from iOS to PHP

Tags: php, ios, json, post

I've been trying to send JSON data from an iOS app to a mySQL database via a php page.  For some reason, my POST data is not available in the php page.

```
- (IBAction)jsonSet:(id)sender {   
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"firstvalue", @"firstkey", @"secondvalue", @"secondkey", nil];
    NSData *result =[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://shred444.com/testpost.php"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", jsonRequestData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonRequestData];

    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

I know the php page gets called, and writing to the database is confirmed,

The first couple of lines in my php file grab the POST data

```
<?php
// Put parameters into local variables
$email = $_POST["firstkey"];
...
```

but for some reason, $email is also an empty string. I have a feeling the problem is in the iOS code, because I can use APIkitchen.com to test my page and I can confirm it works (only if I exclude the Content-type and Content-Length fields)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not decode JSON POST body to $_POST array (so you can't use `$email = $_POST["firstkey"];`). You need to extract incoming data to array (or object). Lines of code for you PHP-file:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonArray = json_decode($json_string, true);
```

$jsonArray will represent the JSON structure you sent.

Comment: so by just adding those two lines, i can access data by using $jsonArray['firstkey'] ? doesn't seem to be working

Comment: I dont know what is your keys in `$jsonArray`. Use `var_dump($jsonArray);` to see them. Was your problem solved?

Comment: I'm finding this works but doesn't handle incoming utf-8 properly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: i know this is realy old but is there no way on the IOS side to bind the JSON String on an POST var. So that the php side just use:

json_decode($_POST["jsonString"]);

Answer (score 1):

What seemed to work was this:

```
$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
// Decoding JSON into an Array
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small typo in Valera's answer

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$email = $jsonArray('firstkey');
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for me:

```
$jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

// with [] instead of ()
$email = $jsonArray['firstkey'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('php://input','r');
$jsonInput = fgets($handle);
$decoded = json_decode($jsonInput,true);
print_r($decoded['firstkey']);

?>
```

Comment: Please try to add more explanation around how and why this code works. Also, try to point out why OP's code wasn't working.